# How to verify Hashed password generated by .NET in Python Flask API?

Tags: python, hash, flask-restful, flask-login

My task is to convert Restful API developed using .NET Framework into Python Restfu API using Flask.

For generating the access_token after login I need to verify the username and password saved in the database.

### When trying to verfiy hashed password the problem I am facing is that the password hash was generated by ASP.NET Framework 4.5.2 `UserManager.Create(newUser, userPWD)` and is saved in the Database and I have to use the same database (same table).

When I am using `passlib.hash` - `pbkdf2_sha1` or `pbjdf2_sha256` in my flask api it is faling to verify the password.

I have even tried `check_password_hash` from `werkzeug` but same issue.

Here is my python code for generating Access token:

```
@auth_api.route('/token', methods=['POST'])
def GenerateToken():
cursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
_user = request.form.get('username')
_password = request.form.get('password')
print(_user)
print(_password)

sql = """SELECT * FROM aspnetusers WHERE Email ='{0}'""".format(_user)

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    auth = rows[0]["Email"]
    if auth and pbkdf2_sha256.verify(_password, rows[0]["PasswordHash"]): # and check_password_hash(rows[0]["PasswordHash"], _password):
        token = jwt.encode({'user' : _user, 
                            'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
                            'iss': 'http://localhost:5000/',
                            'sub': 'AccessToken',
                            'iat':datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                            }, SECRET_KEY)
        return jsonify({'token' : token.decode('UTF-8')})
    return make_response('Could not verify login', 401)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return '', 400
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

ASP.NET Code I am trying to Migrate is as follows:

```
PasswordVerificationResult result = 
passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user[0].PasswordHash, Password);

            if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            {
                //Authentication successful, Issue Token with user credentials
                //Provide the security key which was given in the JWToken configuration in Startup.cs
                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
                var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                //Generate Token for user 
                var JWToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    audience: Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    claims: GetUserClaims(_user),
                    notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
                    expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)).DateTime,
                    //Using HS256 Algorithm to encrypt Token
                    signingCredentials: signIn
                );
                Token token = new Token();
                token.token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWToken);
                return token;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you hashing passwords in two places in the first place?

Comment: You shouldn't need to decrypt the hashed password, and most schemes such as sha1 and sha2 are irreversible (with good reason). You simply store the hashes on the flask side, no need to generate them here, and verify the hash is correct (and corresponds to the right username)

Comment: I am not doing that, the API we were using before already has generated user with those hashes and now they are in the db. I can't change DB values.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that illustrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please read [ask] and then come back and [edit] your question. It sounds like there is a lot of context that you haven't included. For example, are you trying to _replace_ a .NET codebase with a Python one, using the same database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Python encode a string to match ASP.NET membership provider's EncodePassword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456770/354577)

Comment: @Chris I have even tried that like this `def dotnet_identity_check_password(password, hash):
    binsalt = b64decode(hash)[1:17]
    binpwd = b64decode(hash)[17:]
    genpwd = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password)
    print(genpwd)
    if genpwd == binpwd:
       return True
    return False`